# Field template suggestions

Tags: 8, theming, entities

Having trouble getting `HOOK_theme_suggestions_field_alter` to do what I expect. Think I'm missing something key about naming precendence.

Tiny bit of context: I have several `field--xyz.html.twig`  files in my theme that do nothing but remove the wrapping `<div>`s found in my default field template. Trying to create a preprocess function where I can point several fields at the same wrapper-less twig template. Because, cleaner.

Here's what I've tried. Open to other methods!

I created `mytheme/templates/field/no-wrapper.html.twig`

I added this function to the `mytheme.theme` file.

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_field_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (in_array('field__my_field', $suggestions)) {
    array_splice($suggestions, 0, count($suggestions), 'no_wrapper');
    kint($suggestions);
  }
}
```

The result of that `kint()` call is as expected:

```
array(1)
  string(10) "no_wrapper"
```

That is, `no_wrapper` is the only suggestion in the array. But it still uses `field.html.twig`. From the source:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'field' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * no-wrapper.html.twig
   x field.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/my_theme/templates/fields/field.html.twig' -->
```

For what it's worth, the field in question is a Field Collection field.

**What gives?**

---

I've also (somewhat blindly) tried:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_field__my_field(&$variables) {
  $variables['theme_hook_original'] = 'no_wrapper';
}
```

Which puts `no-wrapper.html.twig` at the top of the suggestions list, adds `no_wrapper` as the THEME HOOK but still renders `field.html.twig`.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'no_wrapper' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * field--node--my-field.html.twig
   * field--node--my-node-type.html.twig
   * field--my-field.html.twig
   * field--field-collection.html.twig
   * no-wrapper.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/my_theme/templates/fields/field.html.twig' -->
```

Comment: I can't see in the core code what would be adding field.html.twig back into the suggestions, but is there a particular reason you're emptying out the array? Whatever's at the end of the array will always take precedence, it feels like `$suggestions[] = 'no_wrapper';` is what you need (in place of the splice)

Comment: Thanks @Clive. I tried that as well but left it out in hopes of clarity. Indeed, it includes it at the end of the suggestions array but `field.html.twig` still renders. :/

Comment: Weird. Shot in the dark: try changing it to `field__no_wrapper` and the template to `field--no-wrapper.html.twig`

Comment: @Clive `field__no_wrapper` worked! Though I wish I understood why. I had tried `field_no_wrapper` earlier to no avail. Thanks very much! Want to create an answer for me to accept?

Comment: I will as soon as I understand it ;) It's got to be in `ThemeManager::render()` somewhere but I can't see it right now